# What are unused/undeclared dependencies in Maven? What to do with them?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-2

Maven `dependency:analyze` complains about the dependencies in my project. How does it determine which are unused and which are undeclared? What should I do about them?

Example:

```
$ mvn dependency:analyze 
...
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.0:provided
[WARNING]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[WARNING]    commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:jar:1.1-osgi:provided
[WARNING]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.6.1:compile

...
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:test
[WARNING]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0-alpha4:compile
[WARNING]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:provided
[WARNING]    javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:provided
```

Note:
A lot of these dependencies are used in my runtime container and I declared them as provided to avoid having the same library on the classpath twice with different versions.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382814/.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Not sure how Maven determines this. It is not required to address all the items reported by this, but this information can be used as appropriate.

*Used undeclared dependencies* are those which are required, but have not been explicitly declared as dependencies in your project. They are however available thanks to transitive dependency of other dependencies in your project.  It is a good idea to explicitly declare these dependencies. This also allows you to control the version of these dependencies (perhaps matching the version provided by your runtime).

As for *unused declared dependencies*, it is a good idea to remove them.  Why add unnecessary dependency to your project?  But then transitivity can bring these in anyway, perhaps, conflicting with your runtime versions. In this case, you will need to specify them — essentially to control the `version`.

By the way, `mvn dependency:tree` gives the *dependency tree* of the project, which gives you a better perspective of how each dependency fits in in your project.

Comment: Also, dependencies can appear unused, but actually are. Some examples of this are jdbc drivers or config jars that have needed application contexts.

Comment: Dependencies with `runtime` or `provided` scope will flag up as "Unused declared" unless you use the `ignoreNonCompile` flag when analysing dependencies.

Comment: Why is it a good idea to explicitly declare transitive dependencies? Isn't automating transitive dependencies part of what Maven is good for?

Comment: Raghuram was referring to used undeclared dependencies. I.e. your project A uses library B which depends on library C. If you also use C directly You don't have to declare it - maven will automatically pull it in through the transitive dependency. But without declaring the dependency you don't have any control over the version. E.g. if B decides to update to the next version of C your project A may break unless the update is backwards compatible

Answer (score 17):

The answer to:

"How does it determine which are unused and which are undeclared?".

Maven uses [Object WebASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework that analyzes your raw bytecode. It goes through all your classes and then builds a list of all classes that these reference. That is the how.

As to what to do, I would not recommend removing the "unused, declared dependecies" unless you are absolutely sure they actually unused.

Comment: Thank you! I was experiencing a false "unused declared dependency" warning for a library, even though I was importing and using a type from it, so I couldn't figure out why. But if Maven inspects the bytecode rather than the source code, that explains it: the type I was using was an annotation type with source-only retention, meaning that the usage of the annotation never made it into the bytecode, so that's why Maven couldn't see it.

Answer (score 8):

**Used *un*declared dependencies**
Simply, they are the transitive dependencies which ***you are using them*** but ***WITHOUT declaring them*** explicitly inside your POM file.

In the below digram, the orange colored one.
[image]

Hint:
It is good idea to **declare** them inside your POM file to be loosly coupled against your first level dependencies, so in the future if they planned to change their implementation and not to use this transitive dependency anymore, your application will be safe!

***Un*used declared dependencies**
Simply, they are the dependencies which ***you are declearing them*** inside your POM file ***WITHOUT using them*** in your application code.

In the below digram, the red colored one.
[image]

Hint:
It is good idea to **remove** them from your POM file, because they are not used and to save the final size of the application artifact also to avoid any developer from using wrong classes by mistake!

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily fixed with by adding `ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies` in pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
                    <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>
                </ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```