# Maven - Safely remove unused declared dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565740/what-are-unused-undeclared-dependencies-in-maven-what-to-do-with-them) a question that suggests using `dependency:analyze` to remove the unused dependencies in a project. But when I read through the [sonatype document on this](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/optimizing-sect-dependency-plugin.html), I came to understand that I may have to be careful if I were to delete those unused dependencies.

Here's the relevant part:

> Be careful when removing any unused, declared dependencies unless you
>   have very good test coverage, or you might introduce a runtime error.
>   A more sinister issue pops up with bytecode optimization. For example,
>   it is legal for a compiler to substitute the value of a constant and
>   optimize away the reference. Removing this dependency will cause the
>   compile to fail, yet the tool shows it as unused. Future versions of
>   the Maven Dependency plugin will provide better techniques for
>   detecting and/or ignoring these types of issues.

1. I don't seem to understand this scenario, are they talking about the scenario where if any of the dependency's classes/methods were accessed through reflection API? If so, does maven-3's dependency plugin have a better technique of handling this?
2. Also why isn't there a `unused + undeclared` dependency analysis? A transitive dependency that I have(undeclared) can be unused but still be part of my 'war', which I'll prefer to exclude, correct?

EDIT: I guess the note mentioned on [dependency scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) would answer my second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described in 1. they are talking about things like this (reflection) or may be things like dependency injection (which uses reflection behind the scenes).

Comment: So there's no mechanism to know if a dependency is used that way, unless we look at them manually then?