# Maven enforce no duplicate dependencies even of same version

Tags: maven

We can use the `maven-enforcer-plugin` to prevent duplicate dependencies with difference versions.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>no-duplicate-dependencies</id>

      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>

      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions/>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

What about for duplicate dependency declarations of the same version?

Consider that we are building a multi-module project.
Say we start with project **Foo**.

**Foo** `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>someArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Later, we introduce the module **Bar**, which also depends on the same version `someArtifact`.

**Bar** `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>someArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And **Foo** depends on **Bar**, so we update the POM.

**Foo** `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>someArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As in the above example, and as our projects grow, we may forget that the same version of dependencies are already transitive dependencies.

In my mind, for organization sake, I find it messy to leave these duplicate declarations, such as it is with `someArtifact`.

I could write a new `maven-enforcer-plugin` rule, but maybe there is already a solution.

Comment: This will already produce a WARNING during the build...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, thank you. I am looking for a solution that will produce errors.

Comment: Are you looking to avoid direct dependencies on artifacts that are already transitive dependencies? If so, without the direct dependency, Maven would consider these [used, undeclared dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565740/what-are-unused-undeclared-dependencies-in-maven-what-to-do-with-them), and would discourage that.

Comment: You should check https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions.html because that rule should already mentioned that: `Duplicate dependencies are dependencies which have the same group id, artifact id, type and classifier.` ?

Comment: @Joe That is my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with dependencyConvergence rule. Add this to your parent pom.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <dependencyConvergence/>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Reference :: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html