# Working with Maven parent and modules

Tags: java, maven

I have recently discovered the magical Maven modules and parent system.

I have a couple of apps, let's say A1, A2, A3(there are more).

I have a couple of dependencies sets, D1, D2, D3, D4(not a single dependency, think about an entire frameworks, like Spring with its components)

My apps share the D4 dependency set, so I have a base pom that contains it, B1 used by A1, A2, A3.

Now, the tricky part:

A1 depends on D1, D2.

A2 depends on D2, D3.

A3 depends on D1, D3.

As you can see, there is no extra dependency set used in all apps, so I can't move it in the base POM.

Is there any nice way of managing these dependencies? I am having a bad day when I have to update the dependencies for ever app, I want to change it in an easier way. Remember that I have more apps, so it must not be a particular answer for A1, A2, A3.

(Side note: If you think in an OOP style, my apps are classes, dependecies sets are interfaces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you:

- Create a parent project (`<packaging>pom</packaging>`).
- Make your modules extend it (by adding `<parent>your-parent</parent>` to the projects which extend it).
- Define a `<dependeneciesManagement/>` and `<pluginManagement/>` section in the parent.
- Remove all the `<version/>` tags for the dependencies and plugins from the projects which extend the parent.
- You can also create pom file per type of technology (in your case). For example, you can create `spring-dependencies-pom` which contains a `<dependencyManagement/>` section defining just your spring dependencies. Then in your module which needs spring, just add the `spring-dependencies-pom` with `<scope>import</scope>`. (Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for explanations on the `import` scope).

This will allow you to change things in one central place.

Comment: Your answer is correct for versions. However, my needs are focused on reusing the modules. If I want a Spring + Hibernate setup, I will use the SH module, if I want Spring + Mybatis, I will use the SM module, if I want Struts 2 + Mybatis, I will use S2M module. So, when I start a new project, I want to have no dependency boilerplate at all. How to manage efficiently these intermediate modules like SM, S2M, SH ?

Comment: To be more clear : If I want to update the Spring version or its components, I want that to be reflected in SM and SH.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Perhaps you're looking for scope:optional...?

Comment: Ok, this is what I want. Thank you very much. Any suggestions for not ending with lots of modules?

Comment: Great! Not quite sure what you mean in that last bit...?

Comment: Well, let's say I will have 3 technologies per module(Web framework + Database framework + Database driver). If I have Spring, Struts 2, Java Rest API + Hibernate, Mybatis + MySQL, Oracle SQL, MongoDB, MSSQL, I will have quite a lot of modules. 24 if you combine them all. The example is fictive, of course.

Comment: Heh... Well, Silviu, alternatively, you could attach Maven to your thought-reading helmet ;)
Clearly, you'll have to list those. I mean... A computer can only do what you (somehow) tell it to do. But... Isn't it better to have just 24 (in your case) as opposed to (let's assume) 246?

Answer (score 1):

Use dependency management, as described in the links below, version management is delegated to parent and children modules can use them freely.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_manage_dependencies.htm

Comment: that way the modules A1 - A3 will still contain all the dependencies (without the version). I think the goal is to sort of import a larger set of dependencies. I would use the dependencymanagement in the parent, create a module A0 and add a dependency in A1-A3 to A0. There was a discussion in mixins in a pom.xml but I'm not aware of a feature like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could create modules D1, D2 etc. that have their dependencies listed in their POMs, but contain no Java code or other resources.

Then in e.g. module A1, you could add D1 & D2 as dependencies, and then all of THEIR dependencies would be included transitively.

Then you end up in a situation in which the dependencies making up D1 etc. can all be managed in the one place - that is, in D1's POM.

Is this what you're after?

Comment: Your answer seems to fit, but I may end up with a large number of modules. Can you please improve your answer a little?