# java Maven Project in IntelliJ IDEA, How do I find unneeded dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am working on a Java Maven Project in IntelliJ IDEA but the POM file has so many dependencies from the other programmers that I have a feeling the project is not using most of the dependencies.  How can I find out which dependencies are not being used in the project.  thanks

Comment: Take a look and possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml

Comment: `mvn dependency:analyze` will give you some info

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, see this : http://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2013/05/13/removing-unused-dependencies-in-idea/ In case of dead link : Jonnyzzz Dependencies plugin

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the simple solutions are the best.

One simple solution is to just remove all dependencies and try to compile your code. Fix all compilation errors by re-adding dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the IDEA code inspections? I think it checks maven too.

Answer (score 0):

Try maven dependency plugin.
Execute maven goal:
dependency:analyze