# POM files to use

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, pom.xml

I'm going to be building a project from the [Spring Examples package](https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example/tree/master/persistence/simple-jpa).  Specifically, I am going to be building onto the Simple JPA Example.  When I view the POM file however I notice that it references a parent, which contains pretty much every Spring project you can imagine.

Is there a way to tell which POM files I need in order to have the 'Simple JPA Example' project work?

EDIT:
This is why Maven needs to go away!

Answer (score 0):

Which parent pom is it (and which sample)? If it's [this one](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) have another look at the parent - it doesn't define any dependencies, only dependency management, so that you get a consistent set of versions of everything without having the specify versions in your own dependencies. It's quite a common pattern (look for a [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-rc2-available) on "bill of materials" configuration). See also docs on [how to use your own parent](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot-starters/README.html).

Comment: It's the simple-jpa example

Comment: Found here https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example/tree/master/persistence/simple-jpa  Would it be better to follow the spring.io guides?

Comment: spring.io guides are more up to date, and if the spring-by-exmaple projects all have a humungous parent pom, I'd say that was a reason for not using them in production (but fine for pedagogical purposes).

Comment: Any thoughts on figuring out which dependencies I truly needs vs putting them all in?

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that at the moment (although it's something I've always thought should be automated - it's a hard problem in terms of cranking through all the combinations and having a good enough test suite).

Answer (score 0):

You can move all the dependencies into the project's pom, remove the reference to the parent pom, then use the [maven dependency plugin's analyze goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) to sort out what you need.  There are examples and a rather nifty script referenced from [this popular SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml).