# How to remove unused depedencies from maven project in eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I am creating maven project in which I added many jars. Now I want to delete some jars from project which are unused. But I am not able to identify which are unused. So can any one provide me simple way to identify and remove those unused jar. I saw some solutions but that are not working for me.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the parts where you asked for tool suggestions, which would make your question off-topic.

Comment: Thank you Mark Rotteveel

Comment: Note that you must add jars using "pom.xml".  You cannot use the normal way your IDE adds jar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to remove unused dependencies from a maven pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove unused imports from your source code. In Eclipse it is Source -> Organize Imports. Then you could use the Maven dependency analyzer by running `mvn dependency:analyze-only`. It will produce a report identifying, i.a., unused dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Rosenne.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven `dependency:analyze` to detect un used dependencies. But it wont remove anything.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html