# View redundant dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse-photon

As suggest [here](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/) I have unzipped to the plugins folder but after restart I don't see any new show window options. An alternative is also fine, please let me know if it exists.

Comment: Using something like Maven or Gradle would be a great alternative ;)

Comment: In maven I cannot see which are not used right ? is there a way ?

Comment: If you're using maven, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml