# Is there a way to know if a Maven dependency is used or not?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I may have included many dependency jars in order to get around BeanNotFoundException.

Is there a clean way to know which ones are really used and which ones are redundant?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the maven-dependency-plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml