# Validate usage of the artifact dependency specified in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, ide, pom.xml, dependency-management

Is there a way to find if the artifact specified in pom.xml is being used in the spring project?

For instance, if the pom.xml has dependency listed like below. I would like to know if `abc` artifact is really used in the application code of the spring project. May be there's some tool which helps in doing that.

```
...
    <dependency>
         <groupId>xyz</groupId>
         <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
```

Comment: possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml

Comment: That helps. thanks @Eliwa