# Easy way to build a new project using dependencies of another maven project (Java)

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have an old working application with a lot of dependencies in the pom. 
I use eclipse and I am building a new application with parts of it taken from the previous application. It's taking a lot of time to find the exact dependency (jars basically) the previous application was using for the required class and methods and then add them in the new application's pom.

Is there a shortcut or an easy way so that I can use the code from previous application and the dependencies get easily loaded (both projects are Mavenized)?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, you can check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may copy all the dependencies section of the pom of the old project on the new project's pom.
But be aware that you may be adding unnecessary dependencies.