# Is there a way to find which dependencies are used at runtime with Maven?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to refactor a big project, and there is also a big pom. I want to refactor it and remove unused dependencies. I used

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

to look at some unused dependencies. The fact is that some libraries used at runtime are considered unused, like this answer said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967645/18089908.

In addition, in my pom all the dependencies are missing the scope tag.
Is there a way to see which dependencies are required at runtime?

Comment: At the runtime of your program, there is no Maven.

Comment: I asked the question wrong. I'm editing it

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to do this.

Read the docs and run your integration tests.