How to know which all dependencies used by Springboot so we can remove unwanted ones?
I want to know if during spring initializer we add all the dependency. Later, we realized we aren't using any of it.
Is there a quick and easy way we can identify it and get rid of all the dependencies?
Kindly share if there is workaround for that. Thanks!
I tried to add dependencies in POM.xml but then I want to get rid of all unwanted ones.
Note: I checked there is similar question but no answer. How are you guys making sure your POM.xml has only relevant dependencies. - Is there a way to know if a Maven dependency is used or not?

What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517611/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-a-maven-pom-xml

Remove if from pom file? You can try maven-dependency-plugin:analyze or alike https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html
